# Returning data to parent function

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have a function that sends a request to a server and handles the response in a function. I then want to return the response, but I want it to return it to the parent function (getChannelId) so that for example getChannelId('someUsername') would return "someChannelId":

```
function getChannelId(username) {

    function onSearchResponse(response) { 

        console.log(response);

        var channelId = response.items[0].id;

        return channelId; /* This is the value I want to return, but I want to return it within the getChannelId function */

        console.log({channelId: channelId });

    }

    var request = window.gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        forUsername: username,

    });

    request.execute(onSearchResponse);

}
```

How do I get the response back to the parent function?

Comment: First of all, `console.log` will never execute, as it's after `return` statement.  Not being familiar with the API, I can't tell why would `execute` method let you return any value, so you may want to look for another method to pass data.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here? Do you want to keep recursively called the parent method ?

Comment: The gist of this is to get the channelid of a youtube channel by looking it up via the youtube data api. My problem is getting the fetched channel id returned to the main function.

Comment: I believe `window.gapi.client.youtube.channels.list.execute` is an asynchronous call. You might want to read a bit about it.

Comment: I just can't figure out how I would get the response returned, since it's an asynchronous call?

Comment: You can't, that's the point. The pattern is 'I want to get the channelid and then do ...'. What you want to do is covered by the callback, in your case `onSearchResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

In getchannelid, you should have a variable that the inside function sets. Instead of just returning the result there...

```
var tmp;
function onSearchResponse(....) {
    .... 
    tmp = channelId;

}
```

Then you can return tmp in the outer function.

Comment: This will not work, if `window.gapi.client.youtube.channels.list` is an asynchronous call.

Comment: How would one then accomplish this?

Comment: In that case you should use a global variable, that is, one more level up, outside both functions. Or bind to an object that is global. The point is, you should consider storing results somewhere out of the functions, not returning it up the calling chain.

Comment: So basically have a variable that is a tempory holding spot for the channel id. How would I then know when the channel id has been retrieved?

Comment: There's another (similar) approach if you want to be notified about it: call a function instead of the return statement. But I think you'd like to kinda wait for the result, right? So maybe you could make your call synchronous, wait for the request and then return the value...?

Comment: How would I make the call synchronous? I don't think it is possible to  make edits to the Data API

Comment: I don't know this particular api; there should be an option in the remote call. If there's nothing like that, well, you'll have to implement your own waiting mechanism which will consist of a setInterval/clearInterval part and the outer variable that we discussed above. But it's not very nice. Api should support sync requests. Look for the word  "asynchronous" in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by continuing the schedule in the `onSearchRespone` callback.

Full code:

```
requirejs.config({

    baseUrl: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs',

    paths: {

        jquery: "jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min",
        jqueryColor: "jquery-color/2.1.2/jquery.color.min",
        annyang: "annyang/1.0.0/annyang.min",
        prefixfree: "prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min",
        gapi: "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onGAPILoaded",
        gjsapi: "http://www.google.com/jsapi?noext",
        ytpapi: "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api?noext"
        /*,
        ytdapi: ""*/

    }

});

var player, Ice;

function shuffle(o) {
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};

function onGAPILoaded() {

    console.log('Google Client API Loaded, Loading YouTube Data API..');

    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYTPAPILoaded);

}

function onYTPAPILoaded() {

    console.log('YouTube Data API Loaded');

    gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyBt4dZrv29ut8U0xeYTRFrgH_rB8zil9_M');

}

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video-player', {
        height: '720',
        width: '1280',
        suggestedQuality: 'hd720',
        events: {

            onStateChange: function(e) {

                Ice.state = e.data;
                console.log({ STATE: Ice.state });

            }

        }
    });
}




requirejs(['jquery', 'jqueryColor', 'annyang', 'prefixfree', 'gapi', 'ytpapi', 'gjsapi'], function() {

    Ice = new ice();

    if(annyang) {

        var commands = {

            'Ice search youtube for *exp': function(param) { 
                Ice.execute('watchSearchList', param); 
            },
            'Ice watch (youtube) channel': function(param) { 
                Ice.execute('watchChannel', param); 
            },
            'Ice play': function(param) { 
                Ice.execute('togglePlayback', param); 
            },
            'Ice fit': function(param) { 
                Ice.execute('fit', param); 

            },

            'test *exp': Ice.test

        };

        annyang.init(commands);

        annyang.start();

    }

    function ice() {

        /* 
         * Variables of Ice 
         */

        this.props = {

            order: 'viewCount',
            part: 'snippet',
            type: 'video',
            maxResults: 50,
            q: '',
            channelId: ''

        }
        this.state = -1;

        this.intelligence = 9001;

        /* 
         * Functions of Ice 
         */

        /* Debug Functions */

        this.execute = function(func, param) {

            Ice.flash();

            Ice.log(func);

            Ice[func](param);


        };

        this.test = function(term) {

            Ice.log(term);

        };

        this.flash = function() {
            var oldColor = $('h1').css('color');

            $('h1').animate({ 'color': 'black' }, function() { 

                $(this).animate({ 'color': oldColor }); 

            });
        }

        this.log = function(log) {

            $('h1 span').text(log);

        };

        /* Video Functions */

        this.togglePlayback = function() {

            var func = (Ice.state == 1 ? 'pause':'play')+'Video';

            console.log(func);

            player[func]();

        };

        this.fit = function() { 

            var W = $(window).innerWidth(), 
            H = $(window).innerHeight();

            console.log({ W: W, H: H });

            player.setSize(W, H); 
            $('.video-player').addClass('full').css({
                'width': W+'px',
                'height': H+'px'1
            }); 
        };

        this.watchChannel = function() {

            Ice.props.channelId = Ice.getChannelId(prompt('Write Channel:', 'EthosLab'));

            console.log({ channelId: Ice.props.channelId });

            Ice.props.order = 'date';
            Ice.playVideos();

        }

        this.watchSearchList = function(q) {

            Ice.props.q = q;

            Ice.playVideos();

        }

        this.playVideos = function() {

            function onSearchResponse(response) { showResponse(response); }

            function showResponse(response) {

                console.log(response);

                videoList = [];

                for(var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {

                    videoList.push(response.items[0].id.videoId);

                }

                // videoList = shuffle(videoList);

                console.log({ videoList: videoList });

                player.loadPlaylist(videoList);

                $('.video-player').animate({

                    'height': '720px',
                    'width': '1280px',

                });                 

            }

            console.log(Ice.props);

            var request = window.gapi.client.youtube.search.list(Ice.props);

            // Send the request to the API server,
            // and invoke onSearchRepsonse() with the response.
            request.execute(onSearchResponse);

        };

        /* YouTube functions */

        this.setChannelIdFromUsername = function(username) {

        Ice.props.channelId = Ice.getChannelId(username);

        };

        this.getChannelId = function(username) {

            var channelId = '';

            function onSearchResponse(response) { 

                console.log(response);

                Ice.props.channelId = response.items[0].id;

                Ice.playVideos();


            }

            var request = window.gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
                part: 'snippet',
                forUsername: username,

            });

            request.execute(onSearchResponse);

            console.log({channelId: channelId });

            return channelId;

        };

    }

    this.returnChannelId = function() {



    };

});
```